# Argument of type '{ error: null; complete: null; next: (data: Object) => void; }' is not assignable

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket

I'm trying to get web sockets to work. I have this code, but TypeScript is not allowing it to compile:

```js
let observer = {
    error: null,
    complete: null,
    next: (data: Object) => {
        console.log('Message sent to websocket: ', data);
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }
};
return new AnonymousSubject<MessageEvent>(observer, observable);
```

The `observer` variable is underlined in red with this message:

```
Argument of type '{ error: null; complete: null; next: (data: Object) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observer<MessageEvent<any>>'.
  Types of property 'error' are incompatible.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(err: any) => void'.ts(2345)
```

Any ideas what is needed to allow it to compile?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @AluanHaddad how do I get the error message to go away so that my program will work?

Comment: You're going to run into this issue a lot if you don't try to actually read the error messages. In this case it's telling you something very specific. If you're using an editor like vs code, use the go-to definition feature to view the type information in more detail.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, yes I read the error message and spent hours trying different things to try to fix it. But thanks for spending lots of your own time doing absolutely nothing to help.

Comment: turns out the error message says, `(err: any) => void` but in reality, it only works if you use `(err: any) => undefined`

Comment: Because you're confusing types and values. `(err: any) => void` is the type of a function which takes an argument of any type and does not return a value. However, in JavaScript and thus TypeScript, functions always return `undefined` do not have return a value. `(err: any) => undefined` is a function value which implements that type just as `(x) => {}` is also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [RxJS documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/Observer):

```js
interface Observer<T> {
  next: (value: T) => void
  error: (err: any) => void
  complete: () => void
}
```

You have assigned `null` to the `error` callback, but it does not accept `null` as a value. At the very least, log the error to the console in development:

```js
let observer = {
  error: (err: any) => console.error(err),
  complete: () => undefined,
  next: (data: Object) => {
      console.log('Message sent to websocket: ', data);
      if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
  }
  };
```

Comment: thanks! this did the trick. by the way, I also had to change the second line to this: `complete: () => undefined,`